# matrix that transforms a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused with what the question is asking in this linear algebra question.
We have some basis $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The question asks:
find the matrix $A$ which transforms the basis $B$ into the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

What exactly is the question asking for?
Does it mean to find a basis $C$ such that the basis $B$ will have a standard basis representation (with respect to $C$)? and find the change of basis matrix from standard basis to $C$?

Comment: Transition matrix $T$ from $B$ to $E$, where $E$ is the standard basis. The columns of $T$ are coordinates of $E$ in terms of $B$.

Comment: One could also say "change of basis matrix" = "transition matrix". Not to be confused with transition matrix from stochastic theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $B = \{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$. Find $\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$ \alpha _i b_1 + \beta _i b_2 + \gamma _i b_3 = e_i \quad (i=1,2,3)  $$
where $E=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is the standard basis. The matrix you are looking for is
$$ T:=\left ( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha _1& \alpha _2 & \alpha _3 \\
\beta _1& \beta _2 & \beta _3 \\
\gamma _1 &\gamma _2 & \gamma _3
\end{array}
\right ) $$
satisfying $Tb_i = e_i$.

---

For example, put $b_1 = (1,1,1)^t$, $b_2 = (1,1,0)^t$ and $b_3 = (1,0,0)^t$. Then
$$ e_1 = (1,0,0)^t = 0b_1 +0b_2 +1b_3 \\
e_2 = (0,1,0)^t = 0b_1 + 1b_2 - 1b_3 \\
e_3 = (0,0,1)^t = 1b_1 - 1b_2 + 0b_3
 $$
yielding
$$ T=\left ( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
0& 0 & 1 \\
0& 1 & -1 \\
1 &-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right ) $$